# Access database doesn't update after deleting a record

Tags: vb.net

In my simple application, I have attached a access database. In the form there are 3 buttons for ADD,UPDATE & DELETE. My code is this,

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'NamesDataSet.Table6' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table6TableAdapter.Fill(Me.NamesDataSet.Table6)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
    Table6BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Table6TableAdapter.Update(NamesDataSet.Table6)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add.Click
    Table6BindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete.Click
    Table6BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

End Sub


End Class
```

All 3 buttons works fine separately.  i added several records and updated. then delete 1 record. then tried to update. Unfortunately unable. It gives an error and never update. the error is

Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

Please tell me how to solve this mess.Thanks!

Comment: The error message suggests you are trying to update a row that no longer exists

Comment: Deleting and trying to update afterwards certainly triggers `DBConcurrencyException`, since ADO.NET used optimistic concurrency model and you're trying to update a row which no longer exists in table.

Comment: thanks all for response. but after deleting records we need to update database. otherwise it doesn't save changes made. that is the problem. sometime the error shows as this      "Concurrency violation: theDeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."  how to get rid this mess.please tell me.